# Run Time Error 13 Type Mismatch When Trying to Check if a Cell Contains a Integer

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Adder()

Dim WR As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Variant

Set WR = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Report")

For i = 2 To 200
    x = WR.Cells(i, 1).Value
    If Int(x) = x Then
        WR.Cells(i, 25).Value = WR.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Else:
        WR.Cells(i, 25).Value = 123
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I am trying to see if a cell contains an integer the If statement is working but is throwing an error when it gets to a string. Why is the else statement not handling it, am I going to have to do some error handling of some sort? Thanks in advance

Comment: `Int(x)` will throw an error for any `x` that is not an integer. `IsNumeric()`/`Val()` are other options.

Comment: why the double dots after Else? What is the value of the string that raises the error?

Comment: Oh, thanks @ScottCraner.  That seems counter intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your If in another that test whether the value is a number or not.

```
Sub Adder()

Dim WR As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Variant

Set WR = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Report")

For i = 2 To 200
    x = WR.Cells(i, 1).Value
    If IsNumeric(x) Then
        If Int(x) = x Then
            WR.Cells(i, 25).Value = WR.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Else
            WR.Cells(i, 25).Value = 123
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```